# RxJava do something once 3 distinct events have happend

Tags: java, rx-java

I'm trying to wrap my head around RxJava by implementing things that pop into my head. I'm struggling with following:

There are 3 buttons, each emmiting different events (let's call them A,B, and C)

The subscriber should perform some action once it receives all 3 events (with no regard to order or delay between them).

What would be the <> to do that?

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // Option 1: Merge events into a stream of three events and wait for onCompleted
    Observable.merge(
            observeButton1(),
            observeButton2(),
            observeButton3()
    ).subscribe(
            event-> System.out.println("Button sent event " + event),
            Throwable::printStackTrace,
            ()-> System.out.println("Got all three events")
    );
    // Option 2: Zip events into a stream of one event, and react to that one event
    Observable.zip(
            observeButton1(),
            observeButton2(),
            observeButton3(),
            (e1, e2, e3) -> String.join(",", e1, e2, e3)
    ).subscribe(
            events -> System.out.println("Buttons sent events " + events),
            Throwable::printStackTrace
    );


    System.in.read();//stop immediate exit

}

private static Observable<String> observeButton1(){
    return Observable.just("A").delay(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static Observable<String> observeButton2(){
    return Observable.just("B").delay(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private static Observable<String> observeButton3(){
    return Observable.just("C").delay(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`zip`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html) function.

Comment: Looks like he's not interested in looking at the events when all three have come in. He just wants to know that they _have_ come in. So he could just use onCompleted after a merge.

Comment: @RobWorsnop "The subscriber should perform some action once it receives all 3 events" - I think he is or the question is unclear.